# How to make a column of table b unique only for different foreign key entries in table a

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Suppose there is a table called Emails

```
CREATE TABLE Emails (
    ID nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
    Link_ID int NOT NULL,
        GROUP int NOT NULL,
    Email nvarchar(100) NOT NULL)
```

and a table called Info

```
CREATE TABLE Info (
    CUST_ID int NOT NULL,
        Link_ID int NOT NULL)
```

This is a simplified view of the tables and Im not able to change the columns of the them.

My goal is this:

Allowed:

```
Cust_ID Group   Email
1       0   test1@allowed.com
1       1   test1@allowed.com
```

Forbidden:

```
Cust_ID Group   Email
1       0   test2@forbidden.com
1       0   test2@forbidden.com

Cust_ID Group   Email
1       0   test3@forbidden.com
2       1   test3@forbidden.com

Cust_ID Group   Email
1       0   test4@forbidden.com
2       0   test4@forbidden.com
```

How do I reach this kind of uniqueness in MSSQL 2014?

EDIT:
My goal is like this:

- A customer can have muliple email adresses
- An email adress must be unique per customer but not per group, so one email adress is allowed on multiple groups of ONE customer, but the same email adress is not allowed on any other customer

Comment: So an email cannot belong to the same group twice? Use a Unique Index on both columns: [Create Unique Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-unique-indexes?view=sql-server-2017). Have a go, and post your attempt(s) if they don't work, along with why a description of why they didn't.

Comment: Please explain the logic of what's allowed and what's not, it's hard and time consuming to guess from the results (and prone to errors). Also explain the link between your tables.

Comment: I'm confused.  You mention two tables, but example data only seems to be coming from one.  I think something is off with your data model, but for the examples you give and the tables you give, you will need to use triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly you can't put `UNIQUE` constraint on multiple tables, I can suggest that you can go of one of the following approach.

1. You can use triggers to validate the data before it gets inserted
   and throw error if it is forbidden.
2. While inserting itself you can check if the data is allowed or not using `IF EXISTS`.
3. Create a `Indexed View` and put you UNIQUE constraint on it.

My recommendation will be, create a Indexed View and put the required constraint. To read more on this you can check [**Enforcing Complex Constraints with Indexed Views**](https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/)

Comment: An Indexed View with a Constraint solved my problem. Thank you